# Run rake using Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, rvm

I have install ruby using RVM. Next I create workflow in Automator, which detects new files in folder and then copies them to another dir. The next thing I want - to switch to those folder and run few rake scripts.
I have tried to add next step to workflow:

```
cd ~/blog/octopress/
rake generate
rake deploy
```

But it's failed with error:

> Run shell script failed - 1 error. Rake aborted

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is possible that the shell environment is not right so the rake command fails. Redirect the rake command output so you can take a look afterwards. Just add this, `>>rakecmd.log 2>&1` to your rake commands and view the file rakecmd.log to see where/why it failed.